# Python print name of the variable?

Tags: python

I'd like to ask how to get the string of the variable itself.

```
variable_1 = 'foo'
```

print the result as `'variable_1'` instead of `'foo'`. is there any built-in functions for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the variables are stored in locals(). You can try the below code. This will give you the list of all the variables which have value as 'foo'

```
variable_1 = 'foo'
print([k for k,v in locals().items() if v == 'foo'])
```

Comment: What about `globals()`, if it is defined at a global scope?

Answer (score 0):

@Rishabh's answer is good, but when you're doing the print in a function, and call it:

```
variable_1 = 'foo'
def f():
    print([k for k,v in locals().items() if v == 'foo'])

f()
```

It's gonna output:

```
[]
```

So you have to use `globals` instead of `locals`:

```
variable_1 = 'foo'
def f():
    print([k for k,v in globals().items() if v == 'foo'])
f()
```

Then now the output will be:

```
['variable_1']
```